# JSch "exec" channel unable to create file using "echo 'something' > filename"

Tags: java, jsch

I have written a code using JCraft library to connect to remote using `exec` channel and create a file there in remote. The content of the file is what I am `echo`ing and then putting in in the file using `> filename.ini`.
`echo` is working fine, but the `> filename.ini` is not creating any file in remote.
How do I solve this?
Here is the code:

```
Session session=jsch.getSession(user,host, 22);
        session.setPassword(pswd);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications","publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");


        Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        String command = "echo '\"Hi\"|\"Hello\"' | sed -e 's/|/\\n/g' > /home/myuser/tmp.ini; cat /home/myuser/tmp.ini";
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("sudo -iu myuser -p '' " + command);
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(true);
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
        channel.connect();
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: does the java executable have permissions to create a file at that location?

Comment: yes.  Also, I am executing the command as "myuser". The path (/home/myuser) has the permission.

Comment: its not throwing any error. Its simply not creating any file there in remote....i checked in remote using ls -l

Comment: @Pickle, you guessed it right!! it was a permission issue. I did a chmod 777 and now it is able to create file. Thanks alot !! :-)

Comment: @alman No probs! :) In such cases it is often a permissions issue...

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by the user of the first comment, I did a `chmod 777` and its working.
It was a permission issue.